# Alignment issue in StackExchange.com inbox, achievement dialog and site switcher

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar, stackexchange.com

There is an alignment issue in the [StackExchange.com](https://stackexchange.com) Inbox, Achievements dialog and Site Switcher. The icon is not properly padding with the adjacent text.

The alignment in inbox, achievement and site switcher from other sites are fine. I can verify this alignment issue in Chrome and Firefox.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: StackExchange.com inbox]

Comment: Yeah they probably forgot to update some CSS files when applying the new top bar in there. (Or maybe the sprites image?)