# Alignment issue in stackexchange.com site switcher

Tags: bug, design, top-bar, stackexchange.com, stack-exchange-button

There is an alignment issue in the [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com) site switcher. The icon is not properly padding with adjacent text.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: stackexchange.com site switcher]

**Note:** There was [a bug reported and completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303313/312043) for the Inbox, Achievements dialog, and Site Switcher alignment issue. It seems the alignment issue has been fixed for Inbox and Achievements only.

Comment: What browser? I can't repro on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, Firefox 61.0.2

Comment: @DavidPostill On Google Chrome Version 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit) and Mozilla Firefox 62.0 (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Firefox 62 is a nightly release and not officially supported.

Comment: I see the same issue on Firefox 61, Chrome 68, Opera 55, Microsoft Edge 42 & Internet Explorer 11 (all stable, none of these are 'beta', 'dev', etc. versions). Be aware, it's only on the entries below the "ᴍᴏʀᴇ sᴛᴀᴄᴋ ᴇxᴄʜᴀɴɢᴇ ᴄᴏᴍᴍᴜɴɪᴛɪᴇs" separator, and it's only on [StackExchange.com](https://stackexchange.com), not MSE, SO, MSO or any of the other SE sites.